# Flask with script entry point failing to run with ENV var PORT

Tags: python, flask

I have a small Flask application and I defined an `entry_point` in it's setup.py to:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': ['myapp = myapp.__main__:main']
},
```

My `app.py` file looks like:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# ... All my views here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8000)),
        debug=True)
```

If I run the app as `PORT=9000 python myapp/app.py` I can correctly reach the app at localhost:9000. However I am trying to do the same in the entry_point, which points to my `__main__.py` file which is:

```
import os
from dragoman.app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(
        port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8000)),
        debug=True)
```

This doesn't work if I try to run `PORT=9000 myapp` with the following error:

```
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 720, in run_simple
s.bind((hostname, port))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Why is it not being able to pick the `PORT`  env variable, also when I don't pass the ENV variable `PORT` the application runs, but not on the default port I specified 8000 but on Flask default 5000. Also running `PORT=7777 python -m myapp` runs perfectly on the specified port.

What am I missing ?

Comment: The error is probably coming from somewhere else, as you set `port` not an `int()` value regardless, while the exception shows that `port` is not an integer.

Comment: I don't see why it would run with `PORT=7777 python -m myapp` and not with `PORT=7777 myapp`.

Comment: I suspect something is looking at `sys.argv` too and getting a string from there. You'd have to debug this, add a `pdb.set_trace()` call to the generated script file and go from there?